# Python win32com on Microsoft Excel WorksheetFunction

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, win32com

Is there any way to call an Excel `WorksheetFunction` in Python `win32com` or any other libraries?

I would like to use formulas like `VLookup`/`Match`/`Index`/`SumIfs` in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use the [`WorksheetFunction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-object-excel) object on the `Application` object. For instance, in the particular case of [`Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel), to find the first occurrence of `1.0` in `'B:B'` in the first sheet of the first open workbook, you can do

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks(1)
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)
excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(1.0, worksheet.Range('B:B'), 0)
```